# Leibniz integral rule with multiple variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

In order to find the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ of the function $$ f(x,y)= \int_{y}^{x} e^{xyt}dt $$ I should use Leibniz integral rule.

I know that:

$$\frac {\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x, t) \,\mathrm{d}t\right)= f(x,b(x))\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}b(x)- f(x, a(x))\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}a(x)+ \displaystyle\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\dfrac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x} \,\mathrm{d}t$$

but I don't know how to deal with two variables $x$, $y$.

Comment: You don't have to use Leibniz Rule. Note that $f(x,y)= \int_{y}^{x} e^{xyt}dt=e^{xyt} /xy|_{y} ^{x} =\frac{e^{x^2y}-e^{xy^2}}{xy}$

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I should find the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ using Leibniz rule. I've just edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f(x,y)= \int_{y}^{x} e^{xyt}dt
$$
To compute $\partial f/\partial x$, you consider $y$ to be constant:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = e^{xyx}+\int_y^x yte^{xyt}\;dt
$$
And for $\partial f/\partial y$, you consider $x$ to be constant:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -e^{xyy} + \int_y^x xte^{xyt}\;dt
$$